# Permission required so users can add Required Reviewer to Pull Requests

Tags: azure-devops

Members of my team sometimes need to add required Reviewers to their pull requests to ensure that a certain person actually performs the review.

We have a policy where a group of developers is automatically added to the pull request, which for 99% of the time is fine, but sometimes we need to add an extra person or 2.

There isn't a permission that is standing out explicitly showing which setting to use.

Any clues would be good

[image: Current Permissions]

Comment: There is "Contribute to pull requests" permissions, your screenshot is from version control settings? if yes, are you the project/organization admin?

Comment: The screenshot is from the Branch security, and yes I have project admin

Comment: I checked in the Repository permissions and Contributers have Contribute to pull requests "Allow" but they still don't get the Required Reviewer option

Comment: Ok, I thought it is :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are talking about this option. Some users are lacking it.

[image]

It's  a new Pull Request Experience for Azure Repos. It should be the same permission to *remove a required reviewer* from Azure Devops

When you want to  remove that required reviewer from the `Automatically include code reviewers`, you need to make sure someone who has the permissions to `Edit policies` (`Project Administrators`) to

[image]

**Note:** You need to check the Branch policies of the branch which you want to merge, for example, you merge from `Dev` to `master`, you need check the Branch policies of the `master` branch.

Then, after remove that required reviewer, you could go back to your pull request and click the `X` button:

[image]

So it should be the same  let somebody to make required for reviewers. Try to assign them **edit policy** permission.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want them to remove or change the policy, I just need to ability for a particular PR to add an Additional Required Reviewer

Comment: @PaulFarry I do understand your concern. However, there is no such particular permission  which could control users who can add Required Reviewer to Pull Requests or not.

Comment: So I guess I need to raise a feature request :-(